# Accessing an xml defined string-array

Tags: android, xml, resources

I am a noob at writing Android apps, I have a problem using `getResources().getStringArray()`.

I make an `string-array` resource from Eclipse (or by hand) in a file called *res.values.strings.xml* looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="BlueStartCommands">     
    <item> NO_CMD</item>        
    <item> LOCK_CMD</item>
    <item> UNLOCK_CMD</item>
    <item> TRUNK_RELEASE_CMD</item>
    <item> PANIC_CMD</item>
    <item> REMOTE_START_CMD</item>
    <item> REQ_START_MONITOR_CMD</item>
    <item> REQ_PASSIVE_LOCK_SETTINGS_CMD</item>
    <item> REQ_STOP_MONITOR_CMD</item>
    <item> PING_CMD</item>             
</string-array>
<string-array name="CMD">
    <item>AAAAAA</item>
    <item>BBBBBB</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

I then try to access the array in my `Activity`. It crashes:

```
public class TestApp2Activity extends Activity {
    static boolean firstWrite=true;
    TextView DebugWindow;
        ViewFlipper flipper;
    Button FlipBtn; 
    Button SwitchBtn;
    EditText MessageBox;
    Spinner PredefinedMessages;
    OnItemSelectedListener PredefinedMessageSelected;
    int SelectedPredefinedMessage=0;
    String[] MyPredefinedCommands = {"fsd", "fdg", "sdf", "saf", "w", "v", "u", "t", "z", "y", "x"};    
    String[] cmd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CMD);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {               
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.details);
    FlipBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    SwitchBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    DebugWindow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    MessageBox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    PredefinedMessages=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    PredefinedMessages.setPrompt("Please enter a predefined command");
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.BlueStartCommands , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);        
    PredefinedMessages.setAdapter(adapter);                 

    PredefinedMessages.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ListView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
            try {
                // Remembers the selected Index
                SelectedPredefinedMessage = i;                  
                String s = MyPredefinedCommands[i];
                System.out.print(s);
                MessageBox.setText(cmd[i]);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Nay, cannot get the selected index");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }
    });

    }
```

However, when I use the code created `array-string` *cmd*, it works!
Why is that?

Comment: What ever resource we use in our app android framework creates static reference to them in R.java whole strings.xml is converted to objects when you call getresource(id) it is something like DOM not exactly.

Comment: And so? What is the mistake? Sorry, I don't get it (yet!).

Comment: can you post the error message you get?

Comment: That's the problem with Android, actually, so far, all I get are crashes...ofc I use LogCat, but still it is unnerving to see your app crash at every little step...grr... See below for correct fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to retrieve your array before `onCreate()` is called (you're assigning it in your global declaration).
Try `String[] cmd;` in the class where you are declaring it now,
and  `cmd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CMD);` in the onCreate() function.

Comment: **Thank you!** That did the trick! Silly noob mistake, but, it happened...(wow for the response times btw..)

Answer (score 0):

I have defined my arrays in res/values/arrays.xml and access them with:

```
CharSequence[] monthArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Month);
List<CharSequence> monthArrayList = Arrays.asList(monthArray);
```